# How to Calculate Utilization Distribution Overlap Index (UDOI) in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, zonal-statistics, kernel-density

I'm interested in calculating the overlap of home ranges (=utilization distributions in my case) of a bird species using sighting coordinates. This [article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.2193/0022-541X(2005)69[1346:QHOTIO]2.0.CO;2/abstract) introduced UDOI as the best index for such purpose:

I have ArcGIS 9.3, and I am able to calculate kernel home ranges using the ArcMap plug-in "Home Range Tools" (HRT). I also have "Hawth's Tools" in my ArcMap. Now I am hoping to find a way to calculate UDOI to demonstrate the degree of overlap between individuals.

I see that UDOI can be calculated in R, yet I do not know how to use R. Can someone tell me if there's any Arc tool that does this? Thanks a lot in advance!

I also see that the user "MTGIS" has asked this same [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44389/how-to-calculate-utilization-distribution-overlap-index-udoi-in-arcgis-10) before:

And @whuber explained the math of UDOI in detail in the wonderful reply. However, I am not super familiar with ArcGIS, and did not understand how to do those steps in Arc. Sorry about repeating the same question! @whuber and anyone familiar with ArcGIS, would you mind walking me through the Arc function that does this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Calculate Utilization Distribution Overlap Index (UDOI) in ArcGIS 10?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44389/how-to-calculate-utilization-distribution-overlap-index-udoi-in-arcgis-10)

Comment: While the question marked as duplicate has a similar title, the wonderful answer by whuber does not answer this OP's question. This question's OP wants to know how it is done in ArcGIS, and we need to answer that. Hence it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with @DevdattaTengshe that whuber's amazing answer does not seem to address the "how to do in ArcGIS 10?" part of that question.  However, the only difference between that question and this one is that this one is "how to do in ArcGIS 9.3?"  I do not think this is a big enough difference to stop it being a duplicate so am going to cast my vote that way too.  To initiate further discussion and to introduce the second (older version) I recommend this asker makes a Comment on whuber's Answer to the original question.  I think it is an excellent question (+1) just not an original one.

Comment: @PolyGeo: IMHO, before closing a question as a duplicate, we must make sure that the the OP can get an answer to his problem. By marking this question as a duplicate of that question, we are leaving the OP without an answer, and that doesn't help anyone. Neither the OP, nor the people who will come to this question from Google in the Future. If that question had a satisfactory answer, I would vote to close this Question without hesitation.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I thought a comment on the original (answered but not accepted - for good reasons) question would bring it back to the top of the queue.  It's the original question that I would like to see resolved (if possible) first.  Then, assuming nothing "new at 10.x" is used in the solution this question becomes moot.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe My answer already provided an ArcGIS 10 solution. To make that more apparent, I have recently edited it to provide links to the relevant ArcGIS help pages for the operations in the workflow. If that's not "satisfactory," then please indicate what else might be needed.

Comment: Hi all, thank you so much for the input on my question! @whuber, I saw the links you put in, and understood that your answer is complete and advanced. It is sufficient for probably most users here who are experts familiar with math, ArcGIS and its Python coding. I have to admit that I'm a biology student that do not have any programming background and know only a little Arc (just enough to calculate kernel home ranges for animals in HRT). I'm afraid that the steps you showed were too advanced for me, and honestly I am not able to accomplish some...

Comment: ...steps even with the ArcGIS help page (e.g.,UD multiplication). If possible, I wish someone can teach me how to operate in ArcMap step by step, that will be helpful to me and many other biologists hoping to apply the newly introduced UDOI to their study; if that's too much to ask, I fully understand, and may switch to an overlap index simpler than UDOI if I fail to figure it out.

Comment: I sympathize. You are asking a totally different question and it's a legitimate one in my mind. The key to getting it answered is to narrow it: you can't just jump in and say "please show me how to operate ArcMap"! That is far too broad. Instead, think about what particular obstacles you face. Could you point to some particular aspect of this problem that you do not understand, or have attempted and failed at? Incidentally, the UDOI calculation requires *no* programming and the skills needed are already described in great detail in many ArcGIS/raster-based questions on this site.

Comment: A [search of this site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=arcgis%20raster%20calculation) provides plenty of examples.  The [Web help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Spatial_Analyst_toolbox/009z00000003000000/) for the Spatial Analyst toolbox provides links to pages showing the various ways you can use these capabilities, ranging from operating tools to the Raster Calculator to the command line to Python calls.

Comment: Thanks so much @whuber, I will try more learning from this site and update the difficulties I encounter in detail using my bird data as an example. I can see UDOI becoming a fairly standard way to demonstrate overlap of home ranges in ecology, and it's sad to see some of us switching to inferior indexes because of the technical obstacles (yes they seem overwhelming to us). If I success at the end I'll post some detailed ArcMap operations to achieve UDOI under the original question (and delete this one), so that biologists with no further ArcGIS knowledge can also apply the steps in the future.

Comment: That's a noble thought, but please be cautious. The chief value of the GIS lies not in doing the calculation--that's easily done with many different platforms--but in providing ways to *check* it. An automated solution would skip the checks. Then the problem is that so much can go wrong because ArcGIS attempts to do so many "helpful" things invisibly, including reprojecting, resampling, and subsetting the data. (Such behavior is the source of thousands of questions here.) It's worthwhile contemplating whether people without good ArcGIS knowledge should trust it for automated analysis.

Comment: @whuber That's true. If would be wonderful if some steps can be automated though IMHO, such as the Home Range Tool helped me to easily calculate the 95% UD of an animal, simply by providing the formated dataset and select the parameters. What I had to do there was to study and understand those parameters, and I didn't have to learn how to operate in ArcGIS otherwise with limited time. I have to admit that I wish someone had written up a validated plug-in just like HRT to calculate UDOI, so I can just select parameters provide that I understand the math behind it. 4now ill just do my homework:)

Comment: @whuber just double check: if you guys all use ArcGIS 10, do you think I'll be able to repeat the specific operations that you or someone can show me from your Arc 10 in my ArcMap 9.3? TIA!

Comment: I wrote that answer in a platform-neutral way: the only platform-specific parts of it are the links to the ArcGIS 10 help pages which you requested here. The solution will work in Spatial Analyst (going all the way back to version 1.0 in the mid-90s), `R`, GRASS, *Mathematica*, Manifold, Idrisi, and I'm confident it will work in any other full-featured raster GISes (although I am not specifically familiar with any others).

Comment: Hi @whuber, I have gotten the first 4 steps done:
1.computed 2 KDE shape files(UD_i,UD_j).
2.obtained 80% polygons.
3.intersected 2 polygons and computed the area of intersection.
4.multiplied UD_i and UD_j grids to obtain UD_i * UD_j.
See image: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9fkqIScZLXvLVEyanh4UzFFeWM/edit?usp=sharing

Then I tried to get zonal sum of UD_181b over polygon_181b, which yielded the image below. According to my color settings (which is the same as UD_181b), this is a hole, rather than a peak.
Image: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9fkqIScZLXvR1hlNFpFY1dnWFk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How I did this was through Spacial Analyst/Zonal Statistics.
See image: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9fkqIScZLXvSDk3a1B4MEoxREk/edit?usp=sharing

I got stuck here. I did not find a value anywhere in the result, it did not yield any table or shape file. I hoped to view the result in 3D image with better details as you did in the example, but was only able to present them in the 2D color range as in the image.

Comment: Can you tell me what I did wrong to get the zonal sum? (And is zonal sum the same thing as Focal Statistics?) Thanks so much for your time!
If you need to see my example data by any chance it's here:
[link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9fkqIScZLXvSXJoWVpoWFgzQlk/edit?usp=sharing)
Sorry about the excessive comments, I can delete them at end if needed.

Comment: Hi @whuber, I hope you got my earlier comments above. I'm still confused about the zonal sum. 1)The Focal Statistics link you gave in the "steps" doesn't seem to perform what you described in the math (instead of summing all cell values in the zone and output a value, it sums neighborhood values and outputs a new raster). 2) I tried "Zonal Statistics"&"Zonal Statistics as Table", neither gave me a value that I can find, and I am stuck here. Can you see my previous comments and help me find what was wrong? Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: And I have a question about the A_ij: due to the nature of the problem (UD overlap), do you think replace A_ij with a contour polygon of the UD_i * UD_j distribution (yielded from the same arbitrary rules one used to generate polygons for both original UDs) will make better mathematical sense in this question? - Doing a zonal sum of UD_i * UD_j over A_ij just seem a little awkward to me. @whuber

Comment: Zonal stats are easy and fast to do--the opposite of "awkward." In your penultimate comment you appear to have confused zonal stats with *focal* stats.  If you search this site for "zonal" you will find threads that describe the problems people have encountered in carrying out zonal stats and the solutions to them: they almost always come from confusing the zone grid with the value grid. In the ultimate comment, I'm not sure what you are proposing.

Comment: In light of the protracted Comments here I think this Question is in desperate need of revision by the asker via the edit button to make it clear, in concise terms, what single question is being asked.